# How Does TFS 2010 Build Logging send data to data warehouse

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010, tfs-warehouse

My questions is how TFS 2010 send its log to the TFS data warehouse?

Does all the contents of the build.log are sent to TFS data warehouse? In what way, is it thru web service?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the build log is stored (in TFS 2010 anyway) in the Tfs_Collection database's.

Have a look through the following tables:

```
select * from [tbl_Build] b
 join [dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition] d on b.DefinitionId = d.DefinitionId
 join [dbo].[tbl_BuildInformation] bi on bi.BuildId = b.BuildId
 join [dbo].[tbl_BuildInformationField] bif on bif.NodeId = bi.NodeId
```

Given that the data is in the TFS_Collection database's, it is just copied via the TFS's SQL analysis server setup, in the same way the rest of the data is copied into the warehouse.